# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'. Dart

Tags: dictionary, object, dart

I have a Widget which on some point navigate to a different page.
like:-

```
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              NextPage.routeName,
              arguments: {
                "tag": this.tag,
                "data": this.data,
              },
            );
```

now clearly Even though `argument` parameter accepts type `Object` but it also accepts `Map` since this sentence is not giving me an error.

And in the `NextPage` i am accessing the value like:-

```
tag: ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments["tag"].toString(),
```

Now the vscode is giving me error:-

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.dart(undefined_operator)
```

I don't know why `vscode` is giving me an error.
So, Either the `Object` should have the `[]` or `Map` should be a type of Object.

Or there is something about the Date which is not clear.

**Note:** `data` is object.

How do I remove this error?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[`ModalRoute.settings.arguments`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteSettings/arguments.html)  is a property with the type `Object`. You cannot call an indexer `[]` on an `Object`. Everything in Dart inherits from `Object`, which is why you can pass your arguments to the `ModalRoute` no matter what it is. In order to use it, though, you need to first cast it to the type you are expecting to work with.

```dart
tag: (ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments! as Map)["tag"].toString(),
```

Comment: how does this work for you with casting the arguments which is type `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>` (the mentioned Object) into Map? I can't get this example to work. What Dart SDK version you have used? Is it possible to pass arguments not as simple type like String, but custom class instance ?

Comment: @boldnik I'm not sure what you mean, but if the cast from `Object` to `Map` isn't working for you, then your `arguments` object must not actually be a `Map`. This isn't a magical conversion; this cast only works because in OP's case, `arguments` was a `Map` that was hidden by the type label `Object`. Casting only changes the apparent type a value from one compatible type to another - it doesn't change its actual underlying type. Try running `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments.runtimeType` and if that value isn't some version of `Map`, casting to `Map` will fail.

Comment: This is extremely unsafe, how can we define the type in the route definitions so that we do not have to unsafely assert?

Comment: @Karatekid430 In vanilla Flutter, you can't with named routes as the abstraction between the name and the widget discards the typing information. If you're concerned about the lack of type safety, you will need to manually check the type of `arguments` before attempting to cast it. If this is a dealbreaker, some other options are to use a navigation plugin like [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) or [`auto_route`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) that offers statically typed routing or eschew navigation arguments altogether in favor of a state-management-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

ModalRoute.settings.arguments is a property with the type Object.so you can make it Map

```
final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;

final tag = routeArgs['tag'];
```

Comment: Hey @Mahmuoud! Try to post an answer if it adds to the current discussion and only if your solution is different than the others posted earlier.